# Parent Child Custom Fields with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: plugins, custom-field

i have a navigation menu for Year, Make, Model of cars.

Is it possible to Parent, Child custom fields so that if I have selected 2011, Honda, CRV I don't want other Models from non hondas being shown after I have Honda selected

http://ansamaverick.com/inventory/

Answer (score 1):

What you SHOULD be using is tags. So if you have a cpt post, say '1997 Honda Civic Del Sol' you would tag it '1997', 'Honda', 'Civic', 'Del Sol'. I would make the year, make, and model separate taxonomies and then use a general taxonomy for things like color, etc if you need to. I don't think hierarchical would work because it would limit your selection options, or at least make them more complicated and make the application less flexible, overall.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear, but you should be using a hierarchy of Categories to organize your content. That way only those "posts" (or "cars" or "models") belong to the selected dropdown categories will be shown. Not sure why you're using custom fields.